# How to replace p.wait() to maintain the functionality of the program

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have three files in my program.

1. commands.py
2. argparser.py
3. main.py

The commands.py runs argparse.py, and argparse.py runs the main.py program.
commands.py:

```
def prog1():
    while True:
        p = Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--disable-factory', '--wait', '-e', 'python3 ./argparser.py --command '+command], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
        while True:
            with open("shared.txt", "r") as f: 
                number = int(f.read())
            if number > 5:
                os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
                break # want to restart that popen
            else:
                p.communicate()
                p.wait()
                print("Finished!")
                return # finish whole loops inside prog1()
```

I'm stuck at the communication stage.
The main.py file writes a numerical value to the shared.txt file. I would like the program to end its operation and run again if the numerical value in the file is greater than 5.
I would also like, if the value of this file is less than 5 wait program for closing.

Unfortunately, at the moment, if the value in the file is less than 5, it goes to p.wait() and blocks the entire loop, instead of still checking whether the file has finished running or the value has exceeded 5

Please help,
Regards

EDIT AFTER COMMENTS

```
def prog1():
    while True:
        p = Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--disable-factory', '--wait', '-e', 'python3 ./argparser.py --command '+command], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
        while True:
            with open("shared.txt", "r") as f: 
                number = int(f.read())
            if number > 5:
                os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
                break # want to restart that popen
            else:
                value = p.stdout.readline()
                if value == "FINISHED":
                    return
                elif value == "WORKING":
                    continue
```

main.py

```
while True:
    ....
    .....
    ... some code...
    time.sleep(2)
    sys.stdout.write("Working")
    ....
    ...some code...
    time.sleep(2)
    sys.stdout.write("FINISHED")
    break
```

But... Code still stuck on p.stdout code and wait on break in main.py to recive data WorkingFinished.
My code should READ live generated stdout.write (not wait on "break") and if it "working" - continue loop, when its "FINISHED" break whole loops, not stuck and wait as before to finish main.py

Any help?

Comment: Why are you using popen() to call into one python script from another?

Comment: @ypnos I don't know if it's good, but it allowed me to tidy up the code and enable several popens from one file (commands), pass it to argparse which interprets the sent commands, and finally, several processes are enabled at the same time with different parameters in main.py

Comment: I think @ypnos meant that you should prefer to just `import` the dependency and call an appropriate function within it...

Comment: In any case, see the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen  - `communicate()` will always wait for the process to terminate and is not what you want.  You'll need to set the stream keyword arguments and listen to them without otherwise blocking in your calling program.

Comment: @BadZen Thank you for your answer. I tried to figure it out but I can't send and receive messages live without terminating the loop with the (break) option.  I added code to my post

Comment: Look at the "stdout" / "output" keyword argument to `Popen`.  It is likely what you want to be using.